# TextBox Formatting Troubles

Tags: c#, .net, textbox, queue, simulation

I am still relatively new to c# and .NET and I am having some trouble. My Data Structures teacher assigned a simulation project that deals with a supermaket and its registers. It is supposed to use a list of `Queue<Customer>` to represent the registers and it should show the "Customers" entering and leaving the checkout "lines" in real time as the simulation is going on. Although he did his in a console, I am attempting to use a Form and use a textbox for display, however, I cannot seem to get the checkout "lines" to line up right. It should look like this:

```
R 0    R 1    R 2
102    56     167
234    500    
       231
```

where the "R i" is the register number and the numbers below it are the customer numbers, and constantly update itself.

But mine is a jumbled mess of characters. Here is the method that should display the proper results:

```
private void DisplayQueues ( )
    {
        int start = 4;

        for (int i = 0; i < NumRegisters; i++)
        {
            Customer[] temp = RegLines[i].ToArray();
            String line = ("R " + i.ToString ( )).PadRight(10);

            foreach (Customer c in temp)
                line += ("\r\n" + c.CustomerNum.ToString()).PadRight(10);

            textBox_Registers.AppendText (line);
            start += 4;
            textBox_Registers.SelectionStart = start;
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: A screenshot might help here so we can see what you mean by 'jumbled mess'. But to me it doesn't sound like your algorithm makes much sense. It might be better to use a separate textbox for each register?

Comment: I tried using separate textboxes, but the number of registers has to be able to change and since I cannot select a textbox based on an index (I can't do it easily, anyways), I decided to stick to this idea. I'll add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is to give your textbox a fixed size font. without this it will (and should) always contain a jumbled mess. I recommend `Consolas`. From there on you may want to write a helper function that formats a piece of code to a fixed length. But first things first!

A helper function could be as simple as

```
    public string padded(string input, int length)
    {            return input.PadLeft(length);         }
```

or if your input is always an int:

```
    public string padded(int input, int length)
    {            return input.toString().PadLeft(length);         }
```

or if you want to suppress zeroes completely, as your example suggests:

```
    public string padded(int input, int length)
    {            return input.toString("#").PadLeft(length);         }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that helper method? I'm not really sure what else to do to it other than the PadRight I already have. And changing the font helped some, but its still not quite in order. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: You can look at HackerMan's code! The formatting there should give you some ideas.. Oh and I suggest to pad to the left; the 56 in your example probably should be shifted one spece to the right, right?

Comment: His code works nicely if I only have 3 registers. The problem arises when I have multiple registers, different amounts of customers in each line, etc. and I can't simply pass a constant number of strings to be formatted. I just tried making a loop out of his code as well to better suit my program - it displays the headings multiple times.

Comment: So you can add up the strings from my `padded` function to create lines from various numbers of input in a loop. For the header you will have to decide what they should show.. And if I'm wrong about padding right or left you can either change it or write two functions or add a direction paramater. You're the programmer - you can do anything ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void formatString(string str1, string str2, string str3)
        {

            txtDisp.Text += String.Format("{0,-10} {1,-10} {2,10}", str1, str2, str3) + "\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it thanks to your guys' help. So for anybody interested in how I finally got this to work, the DisplayQueues() method ended up looking like this:

```
private void DisplayQueues ( )
    {
        //Redraw textbox
        textBox_Registers.Refresh ( );
        //New string that holds register lines
        String registers = "";

        //Add register headings to string
        registers += FormatHeading ( );

        //First loop goes through customers in line, seconds loop goes through lines
        for (int i = 0; i < RegLines[GetLongest ( )].Count; i++)
        {
            for (int n = 0; n < NumRegisters; n++)
            {
                //If more customers in line, add to string
                if (i < RegLines[n].Count)
                    registers += String.Format ("{0, -10}", RegLines[n].ToArray()[i].CustomerNum.ToString());
            }
            registers += "\r\n";
        }

        textBox_Registers.Text = registers;
    }
```